# How many javascript variables match each other?

Tags: javascript

So I have 4 random numbers 0 - 6 being loaded into individual JavaScript variables.  I need to be able to see how many variables match a value.

Basically need a function like this

```
function check_count($var1, $var2, $var3, $var4, $checkval) {
   .. routine ...
return $num_of_variables_that_match_$checkval;
}
```

So if have the following

```
$var1 = 3;
$var2 = 5;
$var3 = 3;
$var4 = 2;

var ck = check_count($var1, $var2, $var3, $var4, 3);
```

ck will be loaded with the value of 2, so that I know two of the variables match each other.

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't about teaching programming fundamentals. There are tons of resources out there you're supposed to exhaust before asking here.

Comment: Asking for code is a no-no.  You need to try it yourself, then post what you tried.  That is why they are down voting you. There are tones of stuff on this.  Look up iterating over function arguments as well: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments

Comment: `.. routine ...` yes, you will need one of those

Comment: LOL, yes indeed. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FYI you don't need to use $ for the variable names in Javascript. $ is used as a convention when you are working with certain Javascript libraries (such as Jquery) to indicate that a particular variable is an object of that library, but when using native Javascript such as this, you typically do not use the $ sign. That being said, $ is technically valid.

```
function check_count(var1, var2, var3, var4, checkval) {

var arr = [var1,var2,var3,var4];
var count = 0;
for (var i=0; i < 4; i++) {
    if (arr[i] == checkval) {
        count++;
    }
}

return count;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
function check_count(){
  let args = arguments.slice(0);
  let checkval = args.pop();
  return args.filter((v) => v === checkval).length;
}
```

Comment: Your solution is better than mine : ) But I would use `var` as opposed to `let`. ECMAScript 6 (which defines `let`) is still a * relatively * recent standard. http://caniuse.com/#search=let

Answer (score 0):

I like to do things a bit lower level. Even though perhaps a bit more verbose, it can be much more efficient (and educational). ;)

```
function check_count(){
  var i, count = 0, last = arguments[arguments.length-1];
  for (i = arguments.length-2; i >=0; --i)
    if (arguments[i] == last)
      ++count; 
  return count;
}
```